# CSS alignment issue for social icons

Tags: css

I'm fairly new to css and I'm struggling to get these social icons into the center of the circles, can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/xXXRXE)

Thanks in advance

Here is the CSS:

```
      .footer-social li a img {
               width: auto;
        height: 2em;
     }
```

Comment: If any of the answers helped, please click the checkmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flex with something like this

```
.footer-social li a {
    display: flex; /* change inline-block to this */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Or something else like this:

```
.footer-social li a {
    line-height: 3.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.footer-social li a img {
    width: auto;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.social-default {
    //Will set the padding above the img 18px and below 18px, vertically centering the images
    padding: 18px 0;
}
```

Another way is here:

```
.social-default {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some padding to your img tag.

```
img {
     padding: 15px
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: Yes, no problem.  Be sure to upvote the answers that are helpful to you, that way it improves the helpers reputation.

Comment: My bad, I thought I had clicked all the up arrows

Answer (score 1):

try this

simply add margin to img

margin: 1em auto;

```
.footer-social li a img {
    width: auto;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1em auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

see this image.i have used only on your code.

[image: see this image]

```
.footer-social li a img {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
```

if you are fairly new to css as you mention.i suggest you to use font-Awesome you will get almost all icon here.

here i use font-Awesome, html code

```
 <div class="social-area">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and css code like:

```
.social-area{
  text-align: center;
}
.social-area ul{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
.social-area ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.social-area ul li a{
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-size: 18px;
 background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.social-area ul li a:hover{
 color: #1BA0EF;
 background-color: #fff;
 transition: 1s;
}
```

here is little trick is give height and line-height same value.
hope it would be helpful to you.

Comment: This worked perfectly and thank you for the tip about font awesome too, really appreciate it :)